# Isomorphic submodules of a filtration

Tags: modules, free-modules, filtrations, module-isomorphism

Is it true that $t^{-n}\mathbb C[[t]]$, $n>0$, is isomorphic to $\mathbb C[[t]]$ as an $\mathbb C[[t]]$-module? I think yes, since $t^{-n}\mathbb C[[t]]$ is a free $\mathbb C[[t]]$-module of rank $1$. What makes me uneasy is that the filtration $\mathbb C[[t]]\subset t^{-1}\mathbb C[[t]]\subset\cdots\subset t^{-n}\mathbb C[[t]]\subset\mathbb C((t))$ would then imply that all submodules in the increasing filtration are isomorphic which is confusing.

Comment: That's right they are isomorphic. 

A comment to maybe help your confusion: part of the data of the filtration is the inclusion of each filtered piece into the next bit. So whilst each individual piece is isomorphic, the inclusion is not an isomorphism.

Comment: Your comment that the inclusion is not an isomorphism explains why the quotient $\mathbb C[[t]]$-module $\mathbb C[[t]]/t^n\mathbb C[[t]]$ (in the decreasing filtration $\mathbb C[[t]]\supset\cdots\supset t^n\mathbb C[[t]]\supset\cdots$) is not trivial despite the fact that the ideal $(t^n)$ is principal and  hence it is a free $\mathbb C[[t]]$-module of rank $1$. You agree with that?

Comment: @FlaviusAetius I'm not Mathmop, but yes, what you've said correct. This is quite typical, and there is nothing special about $\mathbb{C}[[t]]$ here. Indeed, you could do the same thing with $\mathbb{Z} \supset 2\mathbb{Z} \supset 4 \mathbb{Z} \supset 8\mathbb{Z} \supset  \cdots$, for example, which might seem less strange to you.